# Best practice for JARs that are associated with different environments

Tags: java, eclipse

We have a project that makes use of Web Services supplied by another group.  They supply 3 sets of JARs for the web services, one set for each environment (Dev vs Test vs Prod).

What is the best way to structure a project in Eclipse that has different JARs for Dev/Test/Prod?  Here is what I was thinking:

- WEB-INF/lib <- all the common JARs go here
- WEB-INF/lib_dev <- for only the Dev-specific JARs
- WEB-INF/lib_test <- for only the Test-specific JARs
- WEB-INF/lib_prod <- for only the Prod-specific JARs.

I can use an Ant script to select the common lib along with the lib for the specific environment.  If I go with this scheme, is there an easy way to tell Eclipse to look in lib and lib_dev by default (for compile and Eclipse WAR creation)?  Or is there a better way to set up a project like this?

Comment: I'm very curious about what scenario makes you need different jars for different environments.

Comment: An external group builds the web services and publishes JAR files to access the web services.  They supply different JAR files for each environment (Dev vs Test vs Prod).  I have no control whatsoever over that process.

Comment: Did you ever reach a solution/conclusion for this? If you did, it would be good to share it with the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use a Maven project in Eclipse (M2Eclipse), and a Maven repository (Nexus for example), which maintains your jar files.

You define in the pom:

- common dependencies
- three profiles (dev, test, prod), each profile with the corresponding dependencies.

For your build, you just have to call:

```
mvn -P dev/test/prod clean package
```

It will create you war with a correct WEB-INF/lib (common dependencies + profile specific dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

**You should not really be building different JARs for different environments.**

Instead, the configuration necessary to differentiate between environments (e.g. database connection credentials etc) should be externalised. JNDI is ideal for this, but system properties or external properties files and the like can be used.

However, if you really, really have to have a different binary for your developers, your testers (hmm, how confident are you that they are looking at the same thing your developers are?) and finally production (different again to what the testers saw), then @Benoit Courtine has suggested a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what build system you are using as to the "right" answer.  There is no sense in changing your build system unless its broken.  If you are using something based on Eclipse PDE build, the following is a good way to handle this situation.

Create a project for each of the 4 jars.  This project will simply contain the jar on the lib path and export the packages that it contains.  The 3 jars that depend on the common jar can also add package imports.  You would then make 3 .product files to build your software for each of the configurations using the .product export capability.

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree with @Gary Rowe, and I will add that the multiple jars seems kind of silly for accessing what I assume is the same web service in three different environments.  The only thing that should be different is the WSDL.

This can be easily accomplished by something as simple as a runtime VM argument that indicates which one to use, and then include all three in the same jar.  We do something similar where we have a -Druntime.env defined (tst,dev,int,prod or local) which then allows the appropriate conguration to be loaded at runtime.

As a side  - In our case we just use the WSDL's and generate the java code with maven as part of the build process with Apache CXF.  No actual jar files required at all.